# Код-ревью проекта. С#.Unit testing

Tags: c#, .net, инспекция-кода, юнит-тесты, mstest

начала изучать юнит тесты.

Чтобы попрактиковаться, сделала небольшой проект, суть которого реализация двухсвязного списка и покрытие кода юнит тестами. Использовала MSTests.
Хотелось бы получить код-ревью.

Буду рада любому отзыву!

Ссылка на репозиторий: https://github.com/juliion/MyList

Comment: первое что бросается в глаза это публичный Node и сеттеры, я бы это спрятал в приватную реализацию (как минимум приватные сеттеры, а лучше полность приватный Node), у вас же получается что любой может модифицировать список в "обход" вашего API, т.е. вызвать node.Next = new Node..., и List про это ничего не будет знать (например Count будет уже не валидный)

Comment: Неплохо бы было ключевые моменты, которые у вас вызывают вопросы, оформить с кодом прямо в вопросе. Сейчас оформление вопроса не соответствует требованиям StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтож, хотели ревью, его есть у меня немного.

Проект на гитхабе.

1. Раз хотите, чтобы вас судили по проекту, озаботьтесь хотя бы описанием нормальным или названием. "MyList" ничего не говорит о проекте.
2. "Установи dot net" не указывает не конкретную версию. Что конкретно установить?
3. У вас список фич, было бы неплохо расширить примерами кода
4. Ссылки на какие то коммиты, где фейлятся какие то тесты - они точно в Readme нужны?
5. Если есть желание показать, что вы умеете в git, то не стоит пушить в мастер все. У вас только 1 ветка на проект. Но это абсолютно не обязвтельное требование, просто пожелание - держите мастер чистеньким
6. Не увидел лицензии в репозитории

Код

1. Названия. Например "List" вообще ничего не говорит о классе. Как насчет "DoubleLinkedList"? "DoubleLinkedListNode"?
2. Node видится как просто деталь имплементации вашего списка, зачем этот класс вынесен и сделан публичным? По мне так это внутренний приватный класс для класса списка.
3. Как следствие предыдущего `public Node Head { get; private set; }` Node не должно покидать List, поле должно хотя бы выглядеть как `public char Head => this.HeadNode.Data;` Иначе клиенты с вашими нодами сделают все, что захотят и сломают вашу реализацию на раз.
4. Хотите делать список свой действиельно расширяемым, почему бы тогда не использовать обобщения? `DoubleLinkedList<T>`?
5. Если делаете класс для того, чтобы кто то его мог использовтаь - хотя бы xml комментарии вставляйте
6. Когда делаете класс для переиспользования, делайте для него отдельный проект типа библиотеки. На надо его рядом с Program ложить
7. `var tmp = new Node()`  избегайте таких названий переменных
8. `public void InsertAt(char val, int ind)` не экономьте на буквах, индекс значит `index`
9. `throw new Exception("Wrong index");` пишите более информативные сообщения об ошибках, типа "параметр под именем индекс имеет неверное значение. Значение параметра -10, допустимые значения от 0 до count"
10. Качество кода не на высоте, тот же метод `public void InsertAt(char val, int ind)` запутанный. Я уверен, можно код переписать и сделать его в 3 раза короче и 10 раз понятней. И так для всего кода.
11. `PrintForward()` почему список вдруг будет что то печатать на консоль? Позабыли про S из SOLID?
12. Скорость работы тут явно не в приоритете. Метод `Reverse()` просто режет глаза.

Тесты

1. Чтобы проверять, вылезло ли исключение не надо try/catch, надо [Assert.ThrowsException](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.throwsexception?view=visualstudiosdk-2022)
2. У вас в каждом тесте есть `firstElement, secondElement, thirdElement` - может сделать из них readonly поля? Да и вообще, вам обязательно их так называть? Да и вообще, вам обязательно их иметь как переменные?
3. Что понравилось - более менее логичное и консистентное наиманование тестов (что тестируем _ сценарй _ результат)

Резюмируя, не все так плохо. Для новичка в программировании, того, кто только учится на джуна - неплохо. Видно, что где то старались (тестов накидать), где то забили совсем (название проекта, например), что в среднем получаем оценку удовлетворительно. Что не плохо, но может быть и лучше.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

1. Публичный доступ к Node нарушает инкапсуляцию, в идеале пользователям Вашей коллекции нужно знать как можно меньше деталей и скорее всего им будет достаточно использовать лишь API класса List;
2. PrintForward нарушает Single Responsibility Principle (см. SOLID), лист не должен знать как себя выводит и тащить за собой зависимость консоли, это не его ответственность поэтому её следует реализовать в другом месте (в подовляющем большинстве случаев);
3. Название List слегка вводит в заблуждение пользователей вашего кода, возможно стоит назвать его DoubleLinkedList;
4. Почитайте о подхода к стайлингу в коде, попробуйте использовать статические анализаторы кода, например Stylecop;
5. Попробуйте реализовать паттерн итератор поверх вашей коллекции (см. IEnumerable, IEnumerator интерфейсы);
6. Попробуйте абстрагировать от типа хранимых данных используя Generics вместо хранения элементов типа char;
7. Почитайте о best practise о том как вести собественный репозиторий;
8. Напишите тесты на Ваш клас для публичного АПИ, чтобы показать другим о том что Вашим классом можно пользоваться и как это делать;
9. Добавьте Summary на публичный АПИ класса;
10. Попробуйте интегривать ваш репозиторий с CI системой, например GitHub actions;
11. Посмотрите чужие репозитории чтобы понять как вашу задачу решили другие;
12. Попробуйте минимизировать АПИ вашего класса до наиболее низкоуровневого решающего поставленную задачу, а все ништяки увести в extensions methods, таким образом вы покажите пример как с Вашим классам работать и расширять его варианты использования.

Много всего другого, но можете начать с этого. А вообще, совет по практике, порешайте простые алгоритмические задачи на общедоступных ресурсах, например на Leetcode/Codewars. А дальше попытайтесь писать простые проекты на основе туториалов. Все понемногу придет с опытом, главное упорство и внутренний интерес, удачи!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!